# URL shortening: redirection to a 'file://' target (file protocol target)

Tags: java, http, servlets, bit.ly, file-uri

I am trying out a simple implementation of a URL shortener such as tinyurl.com or bit.ly. Currently I do a `response.sendRedirect(targetURL)` in my servlet - which works fine for http/ftp target URLs.

However, I'm having problems redirecting to targets such as `file:///c:/temp` (where `c:\temp` is of course on the local/client system).

Typing `file:///c:/temp` on the Firefox address bar works, but a redirection from a server seems to do nothing.

Is this not possible for some security reason? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: P.S. Raj its good to accept my second answer, as it explains the thing better. The reason I am asking this, is because the answer you accept used to stick at the top in order to provide help to other readers. So, in this case it will not provide anything helpful. This answer is for kinda amusement. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't want to ruin the beauty of my first answer, by explaining the thing. Therefore, I decided, explanation should go here, instead.

Well, how can you think to access a local drive of your client, in the first place. Its a security concern, indeed. You don't have access to your client's filesystem, just like that.

It seems that you have no requirement to do that. If you have to, for some weired reason, then you can think of a signed applet or something, I believe.

As far as your confusion goes, that it is working on your firefox. It is because you have the access to your own machine and URL is just fine for firefox to understand. However, inside a servlet, you can't just do that. Read the docs for `sendRedirect()`, it says

> If the location is relative without a
>   leading '/' the container interprets
>   it as relative to the current request
>   URI. If the location is relative with
>   a leading '/' the container interprets
>   it as relative to the servlet
>   container root.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense.

However, in IE - redirection works for 'some' targets. Redirects to local disk 'C:\foo.doc' don't seem to work, but 'D:\foo.doc' does - where 'D' is a network drive.

Comment: Where `D` is network drive and it is mounted. Indeed, that would work, why it should not. Not sure about the problem accessing your `C` drive using IE. What message are you getting, BTW?

Comment: Are you sure, you have foo.doc in your `C` drive? If yes, then there must be something about windows primary partition or NTFS partition or something like that. Not sure, can't say anything for sure. Never encountered this, as I don't have Windows. ;)